# Duplicate of "question not found" stays in review queue when original question is deleted

Tags: support, bug, duplicate-questions, review

[This question showed up in the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/192697), suggesting it should be closed as a duplicate, but if you click on the "Duplicate" tab it shows:

> ## Question
>
> *question not found*

It seems that the same user posted both questions, and then that user deleted his original question after the other one was marked as duplicate.

The bug is that the second question is still showing up in the review queue, when the question being duplicated has been deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The dupe target seems to have been deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798723/eclipse-generates-output-file-but-jar-file-does-not) (10k only)

> deleted by trueinViso 2 days ago

That said, the review queue should probably be updated to properly handle such cases.

Suggestions (to the devs) on how to handle this:

- Remove the entry from the review queue.
- Show it in the queue only for 10k users.
- Dupe votes with a deleted dupe target should be invalidated.

Answer (score 4):

The duplicated question got deleted by its owner (the same owner of the current question) and only 10k users can see it now. Just vote not to close (since it's not possible) and carry on. :)

The *real* solution here has nothing to do with the review panel. It has to do with duplicate close votes for deleted questions. A vote to close as duplicate should get revoked (or expired, whatever) when the question it targets gets deleted. Probably more effort than it's worth, though. This is a very edge case.