# Review a late answer but the question is "not found"

Tags: bug, review, late-answers

I just see an answer in the late answer review associated to a *question not found*. [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/959216).

I guess the question was just deleted because it seems that [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1129167/engr-umair-aziz-attari?tab=reputation&sort=post) was *temporarily suspended for voting irregularities*.

Since it was strange to me, I tried to upvote the answer and the answer got upvoted, hu..

So I guess the review system for (at least) answers (in late answer & first post) should handle kind of cascade delete when a question is removed.

Ps: I don't know if it can be related to [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142363/182741).

**Edit**: The answer is gone. I don't know if it was a manual action or not.

Comment: Fun: the [answer is not deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559230/jquery-ui-layout)! The question, however, is, so you'll need 10k+ to see it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do not have enough rep on SO to see it :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, it got nuked by some automatic process.. weird.

Comment: Looks like the account asking the question was sock puppet account of that user (who is now suspended) which he used to increase his own reputation in illegal ways. When the sock puppet account got nuked, all its questions got deleted.

Comment: This just happened to me with a [first post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1139442). What's the right thing to do in this scenario?

Comment: On this point, why is their a first post / late answer queue at all?  When I review a question/answer, it has already been commented on, edited, up-voted and/or down-voted and perused by many people, usually frequent users of and contributors to the site.  Why not have it reviewed and then released to the general population?  It feels like I am duplicating effort when I review.

Comment: This just happened to me: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1804376